# Setting the NSDate to specific time

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I have retrieved few dates from an array ,which where stored in string format in an array,now again I want to change the date  time to OO:OO:OO when I retrieve it and get only the date without time..My code is as below

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<[keys count]; i++)
 {     
              NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
              dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;

              dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy";     


            NSDate *noteDate  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[keys objectAtIndex:i]];

            NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
            NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit)fromDate:[NSDate date]];

            NSInteger year  = [weekdayComponents year];
            //NSInteger month = [weekdayComponents month];


            [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
            NSDateComponents *timeZoneComps=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

            [timeZoneComps setYear:year];
            [timeZoneComps setHour:00];
            [timeZoneComps setMinute:00];
            [timeZoneComps setSecond:01];

            NSDate *noteDate1 =[gregorian dateFromComponents:timeZoneComps];         

            [self saveNotes:0 :noteDate1 :notes];
            NSLog(@"dates:%@",noteDate);
        }
```

Whether I am doin the correct way or I am missing something,please friends,help me out..

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the date format to

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

also comment out this line

```
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
```

and try again